# Как настроить Webpack + Babel + Gulp

Tags: javascript, frontend

Привет. Хочу научиться работать с современными фронт-енд инструментами, но я что-то совершенно не могу найти ни одного человеческого мануала/скринкаста о том, как настроить связку Webpack + Gulp + Babel, чтобы:

1. Gulp минифицировал JS и CSS и сжимал изображения
2. Webpack мог загружать модули в клиентскую среду посредством require
3. Babel транспилировал код ES6 в код ES5 и отправлял его Гульпу перед сборкой.

Каааак?

Comment: 1) Webpack + Babel : https://github.com/babel/babel-loader 
2)Webpack + gulp: https://webpack.github.io/docs/usage-with-gulp.html

Comment: это все может делать один вебпак

Comment: @НазарКалитюк дайте линк на один хороший гайд по полной настройке. Чтобы прям и минифицировал, и картинки сжимал, и ES6 транспилировал.